# How to drag the box in JS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a box like the below image

[image]

```
<div id="HelpDoc">
  <div id="HelpHeader">Here goes the header</div>
  <div id="HelpContent">Here goes the content</div> 
</div>
```

So i want to make it drag-gable throughout the html page, but i want to drag it only by holding the header. Because if i may the entire box drag-gable then the click event may not work. So how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple if you include following jQuery UI library:
[Draggable jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

It is just one call to make any element dragable:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#HelpDoc" ).draggable(
        handle: "#HelpHeader" 
    );
} );
```

You just have to reference jQuery and jQuery UI libraries in your page to make this work.

Comment: Can the content inside the box is clickable using this?

Comment: Yes of course. In your case it's done by defining a handle in the options. Just that handle will allow dragging the component - in your case the header. I update my answer.

Comment: Is there any option in angular js ?

Comment: There is also a port of the jQuery UI library for AngulatJS: http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#!/